# need to add an output for an image, a hidden id, and a checkout button to this php/ajax script and am stuck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am new to php and ajax.  I have this script that is working for me, it does almost what I want it to do.  But I am looking to add this piece of code in to have the image show up once a product is fully selected and it has the id.

```
$dynamic_image .= '

        <a href="product.php?d_id=' . $did . '"><img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:7em; max-height:10em; padding :12px; margin: 9px; border: 3px solid #e3e3e3;" src="design_images/' . $did . '.png" alt="' . $name . '"   /></a>';
```

I also wanted the 'id' to be hidden, or at least not a selection option.
and to have the price and an add to cart button show up once the product is fully selected.

I know this is a lot to ask, but any help would be amazing because I am fully stuck right now. Thank You!

Here is the select_list.php file

```
<?php
// Multiple select lists - http://coursesweb.net/ajax/
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

// Here add your own data for connecting to MySQL database
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$dbase = 'mystore';

// Here add the name of the table and columns that will be used for select     lists, in their order
// Add null for 'col_description' if you don`t want to display their data too
$table = 'products';
$ar_cols = array('category', 'subcategory', 'size', 'color', 'id', 'price');

$preid = 'slo_';        // a prefix used for element's ID, in which Ajax     will add <select>
$col = $ar_cols[0];     // the variable used for the column that wil be selected
$re_html = '';          // will store the returned html code
$pre_html = '';

// if there is data sent via POST, with index 'col' and 'wval'
if(isset($_POST['col']) && isset($_POST['wval'])) {
 // set the $col that will be selected and the value for WHERE (delete tags and external spaces in $_POST)
  $col = trim(strip_tags($_POST['col']));
  $wval = "'".trim(strip_tags($_POST['wval']))."'";}

$key = array_search($col, $ar_cols);            // get the key associated with the value of $col in $ar_cols
$wcol = $key===0 ? $col : $ar_cols[$key-1];     // gets the column for the WHERE clause
$_SESSION['ar_cols'][$wcol] = isset($wval) ? $wval : $wcol;    // store in SESSION the column and its value for WHERE

// gets the next element in $ar_cols (needed in the onchange() function in <select> tag)
$last_key = count($ar_cols)-1;
$next_col = $key<$last_key ? $ar_cols[$key+1] : '';

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbase);     // connect to the MySQL database

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error()); }     // check connection

// sets an array with data of the WHERE condition (column=value) for SELECT query
for($i=1; $i<=$key; $i++) {
  $ar_where[] = '`'.$ar_cols[$i-1].'`='.$_SESSION['ar_cols'][$ar_cols[$i-1]];}

// define a string with the WHERE condition, and then the SELECT query
$where = isset($ar_where) ? ' WHERE '. implode($ar_where, ' AND ') : '';
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `$col` FROM `$table`".$where;

$result = $conn->query($sql);       // perform the query and store the result

// if the $result contains at least one row
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // sets the "onchange" event, which is added in <select> tag
  $onchg = $next_col!==null ? " onchange=\"ajaxReq('$next_col', this.value);\"" : '';

  // sets the select tag list (and the first <option>), if it's not the last column
  if($col!=$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html = $col. ': <select name="'. $col. '"'. $onchg. '><option>- - -</option>';

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // if its the last column, reurns its data, else, adds data in OPTION tags
    if($col==$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html .= '<br/>$'. $row[$col];
    elseif($col==$ar_cols[$last_key]) $pre_html .= '<br/>$'. $row[$col];
    else $re_html .= '<option value="'. $row[$col]. '">'. $row[$col].    '</option>';  }

  if($col!=$ar_cols[$last_key]) $re_html .= '</select> ';        // ends the Select list}    else { $re_html = '0 results';}

$conn->close();

// if the selected column, $col, is the first column in $ar_cols
if($col==$ar_cols[0]) {
  // adds html code with SPAN (or DIV for last item) where Ajax will add the select dropdown lists
  // with ID in each SPAN, according to the columns added in $ar_cols
  for($i=1; $i<count($ar_cols); $i++) {
    if($ar_cols[$i]===null) continue;
    if($i==$last_key) $re_html .= '<div id="'. $preid.$ar_cols[$i]. '"> </div>';
    else $re_html .= '<span id="'. $preid.$ar_cols[$i]. '"> </span>';  }

  // adds the columns in JS (used in removeLists() to remove the next displayed lists when makes other selects)
  $re_html .= '<script type="text/javascript">var ar_cols = '.json_encode($ar_cols).'; var preid = "'. $preid. '";</script>';
}else echo $re_html;
?>
```

Here is the ajax_select.js file for refeference

```
// Multiple select lists - http://coursesweb.net/ajax/

// function used to remove the next lists already displayed when it chooses other options
function removeLists(colid) {
  var z = 0;
  // removes data in elements with the id stored in the "ar_cols" variable
  // starting with the element with the id value passed in colid
  for(var i=1; i<ar_cols.length; i++) {
    if(ar_cols[i]==null) continue;
    if(ar_cols[i]==colid) z = 1;
    if(z==1) document.getElementById(preid+ar_cols[i]).innerHTML = '';
  }
}

// sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
function ajaxReq(col, wval) {
  removeLists(col);           // removes the already next selects displayed

  // if the value of wval is not '- - -' and '' (the first option)
  if(wval!='- - -' && wval!='') {
    var request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new     ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');  // XMLHttpRequest instance
    var php_file = 'select_list.php';     // path and name of the php file

    // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var  data_send = 'col='+col+'&wval='+wval;

    request.open("POST", php_file, true);           // set the request

    document.getElementById(preid+col).innerHTML = 'Loadding...';   // display a loading notification

    // adds a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(data_send);            // calls the send() method with data_send

    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be added into the tag with id value of "col"
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState==4) {
        document.getElementById(preid+col).innerHTML = request.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that function ajaxReq is showing the list of products? and on select of an option you want the image to load?

This would depend on where your image url data will show when you get the list from the ajax.

I would add an id to the select element and use jquery to insert the image on click of an option. Let's say you add the image url to the  value.

```
<select id="selectId">
    <option value="/img/product.png">Product List</option>
</select>
<div id="productImg">
</div>


<script>
$(function(){
    $("#selectId option").click(function(){
        $("#productImg").html('<a href="'+$(this).val()+'"><img src="'+$(this).val()+'"/>Product img</a>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/kqyfw2s2/